# Scorm player - setting a progress bar as complete

Tags: javascript, scorm

I'm taking a drivers ed course which uses Scorm player and is painfully slow - it requires a progress bar to fill before I can progress to the next slide which often takes 2-3x as long as I need to read it. I've used inspect element to try to understand how the progress bar works and how I can set it to complete once I finish the slide. Here is what it shows in inspect element:

```
<div tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="slide progress" data-ref="progressBar" class="cs-fill cs-brandhighlight-bg progress-bar-fill" style="width: 100%;" role="slider" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="23.04" aria-valuemax="23" data-tabindex="-1" aria-valuetext="100%">
        <div class="prev-progress-bar-fill-preview cs-fill" data-ref="prevProgressPreview"></div>
      </div>
```

So, my question: is there a way I can set the progress bar to complete in the console to allow me to progress to the next slide?

Comment: Frustrating!   Can you post what shows in the inspector before and after it is marked complete?    Some courses do this, they force eyeball time, because, well, they want you to look at the slide :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to skip through slides in Adobe Captivate courses (which use Scorm player) published as HTML5. Basically this: https://medium.com/@barsh/adobe-captivate-how-to-cheat-9bdbb34121f0

For convenience I made a bookmark with following address to execute that code in one click instead of having to re-type it in console every time:

```js
javascript:window.frames[0].cpAPIInterface.next()
```

There is only one `iframe` on page in my case, which is why index is 0.